# (spark scala) How to remove nulls in all colums of dataframe and substitue with default values

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am getting a dataframe which when printed is as follows. Essentially its `Array[String]` data types and at times in database we have arrays of nulls.

```
+----------+
|newAddress|
+----------+
|      null|
|      null|
|      null|
|      null|
|      null|
|      null|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      null|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
|      [,,]|
+----------+
```

So I want to write a UDF which scans all columns of the dataframe and if the datatype is an array (of any type); then scans through the array and removes the nulls. If this can be generically built without requiring taking the column names etc -- it will be great

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame has [dtypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#dtypes:Array%5B(String,String)%5D) method, which returns column names along with their data types: `Array[("Column name", "Data Type")]`.

You can map this array, applying different expressions to each column, based on their data type. And you can then pass this mapped list to the `select` method:

```
val df = Seq((1,List[Integer](1,2,null))).toDF
+---+------------+
| _1|          _2|
+---+------------+
|  1|[1, 2, null]|
+---+------------+

df.dtypes
// Array[(String, String)] = Array((_1,IntegerType), (_2,ArrayType(IntegerType,true)))

val cols = 
  df.dtypes.map{
    case (c, t) if t.startsWith("ArrayType") => filter(col(c), x => x.isNotNull).as(c)
    case (c, _) => col(c)
  }

df.select(cols:_*).show
+---+------+
| _1|    _2|
+---+------+
|  1|[1, 2]|
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the schema of the dataframe and use [spark sql built-in functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) to filter the array columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{filter, col}

// sample data
import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq((5,List[Integer](1,2,null), List[String](null, null, "a"))).toDF

// get the array columns out of the schema and filter the null values
val dataWithoutNulls = data.schema.filter(col => col.dataType.typeName === "array").map(_.name).foldLeft(data) { (df, colName) =>
  df.withColumn(colName, filter(col(colName), c => c.isNotNull))
}
dataWithoutNulls.show()

//    +---+------+---+
//    | _1|    _2| _3|
//    +---+------+---+
//    |  5|[1, 2]|[a]|
//    +---+------+---+
```